# NSDataDetector to detect a name in a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatadetector

I have been struggling to understand the `NSDataDetector` class for a little while now. I've read the documentation and just can't grasp it. Everything I do Xcode tells me there is an error.

I feel like I might be on the right path with this attempt.
How can I write a simple foundation program to find name in a string?

```
 NSError *error = nil;
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeAddress error:&error];
    NSString *string = @"(555) 555-5555 / Nick";
    NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:string
                                         options:0
                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        if([match addressComponents] // contains NSTextCheckingNameKey){
            // do this
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include a sentence with a question mark at the end.

Comment: There you go my fine sir.

Comment: The data detector will find addresses or phone numbers, not names.  Do you have a list of names that are valid, or do you know a name will always follow a phone number + slash, or something like that?

Comment: I will be getting my information in a similar layout as something like a business card so it is hard to say if there will be a consistent pattern. I'd like to have a method that I can pass a NSString into and it will detect the names.

Answer (score 4):

Your code uses a data detector that looks for an address. There is no address in your string. Therefore the data detector can't find anything.

There is no data detector for finding a name.

If you know the structure of the string, then use it. For example, if you can guarantee that there will always be "space-slash-space" before the name as in your example, then search for that and take what follows to be a name.

If you do *not* know the structure of the string, the problem is pretty much unsolvable.

Answer (score 2):

NSDataDetector does not support name detection. Use [NSLinguisticTagger](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this instead.